# Export xlsx file as a link in a mail using axlsx-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, hyperlink, export-to-excel, axlsx

I'm using Rails 4.2, sidekiq, rubyzip, axlsx and axlsx-rails

**What I need to do:**
I need to export file in a mail, but as a link and not as attachment. 
I want an email send with a url to the download for it

**Problem:**
I don't know how to do it with this gem, in the git documentation there's nothing about it and every url I use don't work. I need to know how to create a download link for it and not as attachment to the mail

**Code:**

controller:

```
def export
      export_args = {account_id: current_account.id}
      ExportReportJob.perform_later(export_args)
      redirect_to action: :index
end
```

job:

```
def perform(export_args)
      begin
        export_failed = false
        account = Admin::Account.find_by(id: export_args[:account_id])
        account.connect_to_target_db
        @accounts = Admin::Account.active_accounts
        file_name = "#{Time.now.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_at_%I_%M%p")}_export.xlsx"
        dir_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/exports"
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir_path) unless File.directory?(dir_path)
        file_location = "#{absolute_path}/#{file_name}"
        Admin::Mailer.export(account.pi, @accounts, file_location).deliver
        rescue => e
          export_failed = true
          Airbrake.notify(e, environment_name: Rails.env, error_message: "export account failed #{e.message}")
        ensure
          ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
        end
      end
```

template:

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook

wb.add_worksheet(name: "Accounts") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ["Account id", "Account name", "Organization"]

   accounts.each do |account|
    sheet.add_row [account.id, accoount.name, account.organization_id]
   end
end

xlsx_package.to_stream.read
```

mailer:

```
def export(member, accounts, file_location)
    @member = member
    @title = "Export"
    @header = subject = "Your Export is Ready"
    @link = file_location
    xlsx = render_to_string(layout: false, handlers: [:xlsx], template: "export.xlsx.axlsx", locals: {accounts: accounts})
    # attachment = Base64.encode64(xlsx)
    # attachments["export_#{DateTime.now.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%HH%MM")}.xlsx"] = {mime_type: Mime::XLSX, content: attachment, encoding: 'base64'}
    # ^ this is not what I want, I want to get the url for it and insert to @link
    mail(:to => member.email, :subject => subject) do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

mail template:

```
= render partial: 'header'
= h_tag 'The export you requested has been completed'
= button 'Download the file', @link, { download: true }
= p_tag '(the file download will expire after <b>2</b> days)'
= render partial: 'footer'
```

Comment: From your question it is hard to understand what the problem is. First of all you should check if the link in the email is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure, I just want the link to download to the computer. I want to use send_file or send_data to create a usable link but with this gem it's hard for me to know how to approach this

Comment: try file_location = "https://#{domain_name}/#{file_name}"

Comment: Didn't work, I got "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Can I use send_data somehow?

Comment: what is final url? did you enable serve_static_files in the app config?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: The final url is a folder in my rails app

Comment: You should be submitting to a controller action not a file IMO. eg `download#export` then pass the file name to that so http://www.example.com/downloads/export?file_name=BlahBlah.xlsx. Also as an aside `absolute_path` in perform is not defined anywhere

Comment: do you have any guides and source I can learn from about it?